# Choose Right Azure SQL

Tags: sql-server, migration, azure-sql-database, azure, azure-vm

I'm new to Azure and now trying to migrate the On-premises SQL databases on azure.

I have chosen VM SQL for migration because I just want to lift and shift architecture and need to restore backup file but as I mentioned above I'm new to Azure, So I just want to check with you guys whatever I have choose is it good choice? Which Azure SQL database is good in performance? (azure managed instance or VM SQL) Is VM SQL more costly as compere to other instances ?

Thanks.

Comment: I think the answer to which is best is "it depends." Even the question of cost can be variable deepening on your architecture (MI is essentially an AG, so you need to compare to multiple VMs)

Comment: You mention that you're using SQL on VMs because you're going to lift and shift. If that's a requirement then Azure SQL Database is out of the running no matter what. MI *might* be an option, but I'm a bit confused about how the question relates to the background info.

Comment: @AMtwo Actually, I tried to upload the database on elastic pool using BACPAC file but after 2 whole day import export wizard only done with 51% data imported in azure sql DB. I have 70 GB database and need to migrate on azure.
 So that is why i have chosen Azure SQL VM and restored the compress backup file which i have uploaded on azure storage and with in 20 min I' ready with database on azure VM with restore option from storage account. But I'm really not aware about the pros and cons about the same. trying to understand from documentation but still confused.

Comment: Honestly, I'd recommend getting in a consultant who knows this stuff. There are far too many variables and issues for anyone to give you a definitive answer here. For example, why did you try to upload it to a pool? Not a good choice for what you've defined. Further, there are faster ways to migrate to Azure SQL Database, so you're removing this option based on a bad initial choice, not on actual issues. Please, get a consultant.